# singleton pattern - require(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, require

I've set up a class with a singleton design like this.
The file is called helpers.js.

```
class Helpers {
    //Code
}

let singleton;

/**
 * @returns {Helpers}
 */
const getHelpers = (options) => {
    if (!singleton) {
        singleton = new Helpers(options);
    }

    return singleton;
};

module.exports = getHelpers;
```

That means the first time, I'll have to do

```
const helpers = require('./helpers')(options);
```

And every time after, I just have to do:

```
const helpers = require('./helpers')();
```

For some reason I keep getting

```
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
```

My `require` requires the right file, and my VSCode autocorrect says that requiring it will give me a function that returns a `Helpers`, and that `require(''')()` will return a `Helpers`.

I have no idea what can be wrong.

**EDIT**

When I inspect the return value of `require('./helpers')` it's an object with some basic functions.

Comment: Why are you defining a class for that ? node modules are already singletons

Comment: oops I forgot my exports line in my post

Comment: Seriously *"Node’s module caching mechanism is case-sensitive"*. This article tries too hard to justify importing a not relevant pattern... Its arguments aren't valid ones for the singleton pattern, they just point possible pitfalls.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue This discussion seems irrelevant to the OP's question. Every point there about modules being singleton(ish) would _also_ apply to the manual singleton code in the question itself, so the distinction is meaningless.

Comment: I took exactly your code, just added a constructor to Helpers which stores options in an object variable. It works perfectly fine for me.